# Haskell sorting Map (via List) won't work

Tags: sorting, haskell

I already read a lot of question and answers to the topic, but I can't find my mistake. Hope someone of you can help me out.

My scenario: Get a list of people and amounts, sort out negative amounts and sort the rest from the highest amount to the smallest. My solution so far

```
getPayers :: Map String Integer -> Map String Integer
getPayers m = getPayersInternal Map.empty (Map.toList m)
  where getPayersInternal :: Map String Integer -> [(String, Integer)] -> Map String Integer
    getPayersInternal result [] = Map.fromList(Data.List.sortBy sortPosTrans (Map.toList result))
    getPayersInternal result ((s,i):xs) = 
      if i > 0
      then getPayersInternal (Map.insert s i result) xs
      else getPayersInternal result xs

sortPosTrans :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a,b) -> (a,b) -> Ordering          
sortPosTrans (_,b1) (_,b2) = compare b2 b1
```

If I use `sortPosTrans` alone, it works as expected:

```
Data.List.sortBy sortPosTrans [("1", 5),("3",25),("4",1)]
[("3",25),("1",5),("4",1)]
```

But if I use the function inside `getPayers`, it doesn't work, resulting in:

```
getPayers (Map.fromList [("1", 5),("2",-12),("3",25),("4",10)])
fromList [("1",5),("3",25),("4",10)]
```

Comment: `sortPosTrans` can be simplified to `sortPosTrans (_,b1) (_,b2) = compare b2 b1`, which should be the same as `flip (comparing snd)`.

Comment: @melpomene: Thats correct, thanks for this advice, I will update the question, but doesn't solve the problem :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can't sort a `Map`. That's why `sortBy` takes and returns a list. A `Map` is always internally sorted by keys, which is what allows efficient lookup and insertion:

```
*> Map.fromList [("3",25),("1",5),("4",1)]
fromList [("1",5),("3",25),("4",1)]
```

If you want your results to be sorted according to a custom criterion, return a list instead.

Comment: Does it also mean, if I want to 'sort' a map, I need to sort the key (or in my case change the key) to get the expected sorting?

Comment: @sandkasten Yeah, you can either change your keys so that the default `compare` order matches what you want, or you can keep a secondary list of keys in the order you want, then use that list to access the values.

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick response.